# Emit value from child to parent component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

In my Nuxt.js application, I try to emit a value from child to parent component.

The parent component is: **pages/index.vue**:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <custom-input v-model="value" />
    <v-btn @click="showValue">
      Ok
    </v-btn>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import CustomInput from '@/components/CustomInput.vue'
export default {
  components: { CustomInput },
  data () {
    return {
      value: 'hello'
    }
  },
  watch: {
    value (val) {
      console.log('value' + val)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    showValue () {
      console.log('value is: ' + this.value)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The child is: **component/CustomInput.vue**:

```
<template>
  <v-text-field
    v-bind:value="value"
    v-on:input="$emit('input', value)"
  />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'CustomInput',
  props: {
    value: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  watch: {
    value () {
      this.$emit('input', this.value)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

When I click on the button Ok, I am not getting the updated value. What am I missing ?

[image]
Screenshot shows the new value is not console logged on a button click, instead the old one is displayed.

I followed the official documentation [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components)

Related simple [demo](https://github.com/begueradj/nuxt-vmodel) is hosted on Github.

Comment: You have lots of other console logging in your code. Which of those do you see log as expected?

Comment: Just for debugging, I will remove them, and leave the relevant ones only

Comment: But do you see the console logging for the `watch` on `value`?

Comment: What I need is: on the click of the button, I would like to console log the value I typed. All other console logs were there just for debugging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
v-on:input="$emit('input', value)"
```

This is emitting the old value.

It should be:

```
v-on:input="$emit('input', $event)"
```

This will emit the new value.

Alternatively you could use:

```
v-on:input="value => $emit('input', value)"
```

Or move it out to a method in `methods`.

Comment: Both the link to the documentation I shared and [this tutorial](https://zaengle.com/blog/using-v-model-on-nested-vue-components) did what I attempted (I just followed their steps). Thank you very much

Comment: @Begueradj I can't see anywhere in either resource that does what you attempted. I suspect you may be misinterpreting what you read.

Comment: On the tutorial it uses : `this.$emit('input', this.value);`, the difference with mine was `this` which I attempted before posting (sorry for not mentioning it). I did what the documentation says but I was getting something like: **trying to read value of undefined**. Thank you for the help

Comment: @Begueradj The key difference is where the code appears. In the tutorial that code appears inside a `watch` and is run after `this.value` has changed to a new value. In your code you're using it as a listener for an `input` event. These are two totally different scenarios. It is really important that you understand why your code didn't work. Removing the `this.` prefix is normal when you migrate code to a template, that is not the problem here.

Comment: Sorry to come back to you again: I want to name my prop something else other than `value`, but when I do, I get this error: `missing required prop propNameIchose`. How could we rename the prop ?

Comment: @Begueradj If you still want to use the prop with `v-model` then you'll need to use the `model` option on the component to configure the prop name: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#model. An alternative is using the `sync` modifier instead of `v-model`: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier. A further alternative is manually handling the binding and event listener in the parent component rather than relying on Vue's two-way binding.